# THREE.DragControls is not a constructor error

Tags: javascript, drag-and-drop

I am trying to use Three.DragControls constructor for my application in three.js.
I run npm install and npm install three-dragcontrols, receiving the message the dependency was added to the package.
When i am trying to use new Three.DragControls i receive the error:
"THREE.DragControls is not a constructor"

The code:

```
var scene = new THREE.Scene();
scene.background = new THREE.Color( 0xf0f0f0 );
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 70, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 10000 );
var objects = [];

var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

camera.position.z = 1000;

var startColor;

function init() {
    scene.add( new THREE.AmbientLight( 0x0f0f0f ) );

    var light = new THREE.SpotLight( 0xffffff, 1.5 );
    light.position.set( 0, 500, 2000 );

    scene.add(light);

    var geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry( 40, 40, 40 );
    var geometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry( 40, 40, 40 );

    for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        var object = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial( { color: Math.random() * 0xffffff } ) );

        object.position.x = Math.random() * 1000 - 500;
        object.position.y = Math.random() * 600 - 300;
        object.position.z = Math.random() * 800 - 400;

        object.castShadow = true;
        object.receiveShadow = true;

        scene.add( object );

        objects.push( object );
    }

    var controls = new THREE.DragControls( objects, camera, renderer.domElement );
    controls.addEventListener( 'dragstart', dragStartCallback );
    controls.addEventListener( 'dragend', dragendCallback );
}

function dragStartCallback(event) {
    startColor = event.object.material.color.getHex();
    event.object.material.color.setHex(0x000000);
}

function dragendCallback(event) {
    event.object.material.color.setHex(startColor);
}

function animate() {
    requestAnimationFrame( animate );

    renderer.render(scene, camera);
};

init();
animate();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Possible answer (can't post this as a comment because of SO's stupid rules):

Please share the part of your code in which you import/require the module. In many cases with these modules for Three.js you have to attach them to the `THREE` object.

For example:

```
// Doesn't work:
THREE.DragControls = require("three-drag-controls");

// Does work:
THREE.DragControls = require("three-drag-controls")(THREE);
```

This is because the module is in fact a function which returns the constructor for the controls. If you don't run the function first with `THREE` as an argument, you get "THREE.DragControls is not a constructor".

Comment: Please mark as accepted if this worked, or provide more info if you're still struggling with it.

Answer (score 3):

For those coming here while trying to follow the 'Three.js Drag and Drop Tutorial' and get stuck with the above error message, the solution is to install the Drag Controls module and follow the usage instructions on the repo (https://www.npmjs.com/package/drag-controls), namely changing the imports to:

```
import * as THREE from 'three';
import DragControls from 'drag-controls'
DragControls.install({THREE: THREE})
```

And then creating the DragControls instance this way:

```
var controls = new DragControls( objects, camera, renderer.domElement );
```

Things should work after that.
Hope this saved some of you some time!

Comment: Thanks Jon you were right on the bat with that one. enjoy the 10 rep..lol you earned it